# SP-IdP interaction issue: I'm not redirected back to SP web site

Tags: single-sign-on, wif, saml, adfs2.0, adfs

I'm new in SSO and ADFS, so I tried to run this guide first: [AD FS 2.0 Federation with a WIF Application Step-by-Step Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-federation-wif-application-step-by-step-guide%28WS.10%29.aspx). This guide implies single machine is used to run it, but I run Identity Provider (IdP) and Service Provider (SP) on 2 separate machines. I got a problem on the last step when IdP supposed to redirect authenticated request back to SP's web site, instead it returns HTTP 200 Ok leaving me on on IdP web site. Use case: As I request SP page in a browser (IE8) it redirects me to IdP as expected. It shows me popup window where I enter my windows account credentials. However instead of getting me back to SP web page it displays me content of //adfsserver/adfs/ls folder.

According to Fiddler this is how http authentication request/responses look like:

GET https://adfsserver/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2fymichurin%2fClaimsAwareWebAppWithManagedSTS%2f&wctx=rm%3d0%26id%3dpassive%26ru%3d%252fClaimsAwareWebAppWithManagedSTS%252fdefault.aspx&wct=2011-11-23T21%3a59%3a56Z HTTP/1.1
...

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
*Here is //adfsserver/adfs/ls folder content*

Is any idea what's wrong?

Does anybody know similar ADFS guide that shows how this stuff works on separate machines, not on a single one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved. It was because of running Fiddler.

BTW, I still can not run it under FireFox, only IE works properly. FireFox asks for credentials showing me popup window, but does not want to authenticate me as I enter correct user name/password. Kerboros works fine for Firefox, I checked it up building sample asp.net web app and putting it to the same web server (IdP), but looks like adfs\ls directory works different way, it handles credentials manually and something seems to be wrong with this handling. Note Firefox does not work in Windows version only, Firefox for iOS works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It should work exactly the same on two servers. I've done this heaps of times.

Essentially, run FedUtil on your app. pointing to the ADFS metadata (Use existing STS) and then configure the app. as a RP on ADFS (Import data about RP published online) and then configure some claims.

From your RP server, can you browse to https://{your_federation_service_name}/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?

From your ADFS server, can you browse to your RP app. (using https)?

In your RP web.config, check that the federatedAuthentication section points to ADFS.

In ADFS, double click on your RP. Check that the url in the Identifiers tab is correct.

From the ADFS server, in the Event Viewer, look under "Applications and Services Log" / AD FS 2.0 and see if any errors.

Comment: Both IdP and SP are browsable with https. 
This is how my federatedAuthentication looks like: 
 `<wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://adfsserver/adfs/ls/" realm="https://spsserver/ClaimsAwareWebAppWithManagedSTS/" requireHttps="true" />`. Identifiers tab looks fine too. No errors in log on both sides

Comment: What seems strange to me is that there is no wreply parameter as part of uri from SPS to IdP, so it's likely IdP just does not know where to redirect the user to. I do not see any information regarding 'Reply back to' URI at all in Fiddler, neither in URI nor in a Message body

Comment: If you have VS and you have installed WIF and the WIF SDK on your dev. box, try File / New / Web Site / Claims-aware ASP.NET Web Site and then do the Add STS / Configure RP stuff and see what happens.

Comment: Should I put this new web site under IIS? Or should I specify http://localhost:51515/ClaimsAwareWebSite1/ as Application URI in the wizard? On the STS step should I select 'Use an existing STS' option specify adfserver name

Comment: Right click the project, Properties / Web / click Use Local IIS Web Server and then the Create Virtual Directory button works best to put it in IIS. Cassini (the built in web server) has problems with https. For Add STS, use the full name of the Application URI i.e. https://Server Name/App Name rather than localhost/App Name. Then use existing STS and point to adfserver.

Comment: What you just said is true for Web Application type of project, but not for Web site. I have no option in small property window to make it work under IIS. That's why I asked

Comment: The same result unfortunately:( List of files of //adfsserver/adfs/ls is displayed though it correctly identifies me. The same result on both sides: if browse SP from SP and IdP. It sounds like handler for adfs/ls path does not work on IdP side, though it's registered properly under IIS